# Facebook graph public fields

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following rest url:
facebook.com/4?fields=about,birthday,education,bio,age_range,email,first_name,gender

I don't understand why it shows only the name and id? I thought that those fields are public, or am I wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, of course you have to get permission from the user before getting any data: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

"Public" does not mean you can grab everything with an App. And you should always use `/me` instead of `/user-id`. `/me` points to the authorized user, there is no need to use the id.

Comment: Sorry, for apparently being a stupid question, but my goal is to get some demographic info about the users who are going to share like my posts. I know that there are many social media websites who gives many infos about who shares/likes your posts

Comment: that´s not possible at all. you can only get data of users who authorized your app.

Comment: What about getting information about who shared/liked a post from a public page. The scenario is like so : I have a small website which I want to promote so I ask different person who have public social media page, to post something about my website. And who ever gets more likes/shares on their post will win. I'm pretty sure that this is doable because there are many tools on the internet does this. ex: https://neoreach.com/

Comment: just take a look at the facebook docs and do some research and testing with the api explorer. you can get the number of likes and shares easily with the feed endpoint, but that´s a completely different question.

Comment: Hi, I already  look over your suggestion, and I found this endpoint:https://graph.facebook.com/10150160813853553/likes ,. This tells who liked a post. But it seems that this works only with the post from my own facebook page. Isn't possible to get information about posts from public pages? (In my case who is gonna post something about my campaign ) ?

Comment: it does work with public pages, but you may need a user token if the page is restricted by age or location. else, an app token is good enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101308/discussion-between-catalin-and-luschn).

Comment: Ok, I got it, although it looks pretty restrictive. In this case how social crawlers work ? As far as I know these crawlers are getting information from everywhere: facebook, twitter,instagram etc

Comment: well, they most likely scrape profile pages, which is not allowed on facebook. or they only get the names and ids, which you are doing right now. even that would be a privacy issue, you can´t just store names and ids of users somewhere without their authorization. that fact that some platforms do it does not mean it´s allowed.